# Загрузка документов на веб-сайты в WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

У меня есть простое приложение с одним вебвью на весь экран. Сейчас, когда я на каких-нибудь сайтах (гугл документы при загрузке файлов, почта при прикреплении файла к письму и т.д.) нажимаю на кнопки, предлагающие выбрать приложение для загрузки файлов (галерея, проводники и т.д.), ничего не происходит, например, тут:

[image]

Хотелось бы заставить их работать как в мобильном браузере, где при нажатии на кнопку прикрепления на любом веб-сайте, видимо, срабатывает Inplicit Intent, который предлагает выбрать соответствующее приложение.

Я скопом указал кучу Permissons из тех, что нашел, но эффекта нет:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать, не знаю даже, в какую сторону копать и где и как это прописывать.

Проект состоит из двух файлов:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)


        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore the previous URL and history stack
            binding.webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        }

        val myWebViewClient = MyWebViewClient(this)
        binding.webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

        val currentUrl = myWebViewClient.sharedPref.getString(URL, "https://www.google.ru")

        Log.d(tag, "sharedPref value: ${myWebViewClient.sharedPref.getString(URL, "")}")
        if (currentUrl != null) {
            binding.webView.loadUrl(currentUrl)
        }
        binding.webView.webViewClient = myWebViewClient
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        binding.webView.apply {
            if (canGoBack()) {
                goBack()
            } else {
                onBackPressed()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MyWebViewClient class:

```
val tag = "CUSTOMTAG"

val SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs"
val URL = "URL"

class MyWebViewClient(val context: Context) : WebViewClient() {

    val sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        SHARED_PREFS,
        AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE
    )


    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String): Boolean {
        view?.let {
            it.loadUrl(url)
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url)

        with(sharedPref.edit()) {
            putString(URL, url)
            apply()
        }

        if (url != null) {
            sharedPref.getString(URL, "")?.let { Log.d(tag, "sharedPref: $it") }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается с помощью WebChromeClient, где надо переопределить пару методов onShowFileChooser и openFileChooser, примерно так:

```
val webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {

        override fun onShowFileChooser(mWebView: WebView?, filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>, fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams): Boolean {
            mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback
            val intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent()
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE)
            return true
        }

        protected fun openFileChooser(uploadMsg: ValueCallback<Uri>, acceptType: String?, capture: String?) {
            mUploadMsg = uploadMsg
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            intent.type = "image/*"
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Title"), REQ_CODE)
        }
    }
    webView.webChromeClient = webChromeClient
```

И в onActivityResult, вызывать колбэк:

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == REQ_CODE) {
        val mFilePathCallbackCurr = mFilePathCallback
        if (mFilePathCallbackCurr == null) {
            return
        } else {
            mFilePathCallbackCurr.onReceiveValue(FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent))
            mFilePathCallbackCurr = null
        }
    }
}
```

Есть заморочки со старыми версиями андроид, для них есть перегруженные варианты метода onShowFileChooser

Comment: Спасибо, но один момент не понял - mFilePathCallback в вашей варианте - имеется в виду ссылка на текущую страницу?

Comment: Да, это колбэк который вернет выбранный пользователем фаил в браузер. В onShowFileChooser() браузер дает тебе объект filePathCallback, у которого есть метод onReceiveValue() загружающий файл. Поэтому ты должен сохранить ссылку на этот объект в mFilePathCallback , чтоб использовать в onActivityResult